# Jekyll issue(s) on macOS Monterey (12.3)

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll, bundler

I upgraded to macOS 12.3 recently and that broke my jekyll website. When I first tried to build my website after the upgrade, my computer (Macbook Air with Intel chip) would crash.

So far, I have upgraded homebrew and addressed all warnings:

```
$ brew -v
Homebrew 3.4.3
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 0d76941ceaf; last commit 2022-03-26)
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

I have installed version 3.0.2 of ruby using rbenv:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin21]
```

I followed the steps outlined at https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/using-jekyll-with-bundler/ to create a new site in order to compare it to old site that has been crashing my computer. I endeavoured to ensure that the contents of my old site directory matched the new site directory. The new site builds, but I get following error when I try to build the old site:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll s -t
Generating... 
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/Users/hepting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1466:in `unlink': Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/_site/research/works (Errno::EPERM)
```

Jekyll is there:

```
$ /Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll -v
jekyll 4.2.2
```

This is the "research/works" directory for my old site:

```
$ ls -l research/works
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 hepting  staff  128 23 Oct  2018 0_nonweb
-rw-r--r--  1 hepting  staff  798 21 Jan  2020 index.md
```

and this index.md file contains (in part):

```
---
layout: w_collection
title: Collected Works
redirect_from:
  - /research/works.html
breadcrumb: Collected Works
collection: works
---
```

I have the following defined in my `_config.yml` for research/works. I didn't think that the problem was here since it has worked fine for years. On the web, the page is at [http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hepting/research/works/](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Ehepting/research/works/)

```
collections:
  - works

collections:
  works:
    output: true
    permalink: /research/:collection/:title:output_ext
```

Here's the Gemfile that I use for both sites:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.

gem "jekyll", "~> 4.2.2"
gem "minima", "~> 2.5"
gem "webrick", "~> 1.7"
gem "nokogiri", '>= 1.12.5'
gem 'html-proofer', '>= 3.15.3'

group :jekyll_plugins do
   gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
   gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
   gem 'jekyll-redirect-from'
end
```

I have the following .bundle/config:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

When I do "bundle install" (in the old site directory):

```
$ bundle install
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using bundler 2.3.10
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using eventmachine 1.2.7
Using http_parser.rb 0.8.0
Using em-websocket 0.5.3
Using ffi 1.15.5
Using ethon 0.15.0
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using mercenary 0.4.0
Using mini_portile2 2.8.0
Using racc 1.6.0
Using nokogiri 1.13.3 (x86_64-darwin)
Using parallel 1.22.1
Using rainbow 3.1.1
Using typhoeus 1.4.0
Using yell 2.2.2
Using html-proofer 3.19.3
Using i18n 1.10.0
Using sassc 2.4.0
Using jekyll-sass-converter 2.2.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using listen 3.7.1
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using kramdown 2.3.2
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using rouge 3.28.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using unicode-display_width 1.8.0
Using terminal-table 2.0.0
Using jekyll 4.2.2
Using jekyll-feed 0.16.0
Using jekyll-redirect-from 0.16.0
Using jekyll-seo-tag 2.8.0
Using jekyll-sitemap 1.4.0
Using minima 2.5.1
Using webrick 1.7.0
Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 43 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
```

When I do "bundle install" (in the new site directory):

```
Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 42 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
```

The difference appears to be "mini_portile2 2.8.0". I've tried to remove it but it gets pulled back in with "bundle install".

Any suggestions about how to resolve my problem building my old site? Any information that I didn't provide?

Best regards,
Daryl

Comment: The dependancies are not only in `Gemfile` as soon as you do have a `Gemfile.lock` — which is created after a successful install.  Try removing this file, the vendor directory, and `bundle install` it again.

Comment: Thanks. After doing what you suggested, I was able to remove that extra gem from the bundle, but I still get the errors when I try to build the site: `bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/jekyll)
/Users/hepting/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1466:in unlink, Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/_site/research/works (Errno::EPERM)`

Comment: Is `/Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/_site/research/works` an existing folder on your machine?

Comment: What you can also try to do is `brew cleanup`.

Comment: I just did a `brew cleanup` and it did not print any messages. I'll put a bit more about the research/works directory + my config file in an edit to the question.

Comment: Actually the `_site` folder is the one generated by Jekyll with your compiled website, based on the actual _"code"_ files. So you should be able to safely do: `rm -Rf /Users/hepting/Sites/dhhepting.github.io/_site`, then try to build the site again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the site to build by hiding the content related to "research/works" (a collection) and that felt like an incomplete answer.

I think that my answer is more complete now: it seems that subdirectories now cause problems within collections (at least the ones with output). I removed the subdirectory so that all items in my _works collection are directly contained in the _works directory and my site is now building as it once was.